# Open mapping theorem and isomorphism

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X,Y$ be two Banach spaces and $T \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ be an isomorphism. I have to prove the following:
$$\overline{T(B(0,1))} = T(\overline{B(0,1)})  $$

I have some questions regarding the statement and (potential) proof:

1. Interpretation of the statement: If I have an isomorph operator $T \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ the image of a closed set is closed (I think, that is in general not true, therefore OPEN mapping Thm., but with the operator being bijective the statements holds). Are these interpretations so far correct?
2. Thoughts regarding the proof: Since $T$ is bijective, we have also $T^{-1} \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$. Now I started trying the following:
   $$T^{-1}(T(\overline{B(0,1)})) = \overline{B(0,1)} $$
   Since preimages of closed sets are closed, $T(\overline{B(0,1)})$ has to be closed, i.e.
   $$\overline{T(B(0,1))} = T(\overline{B(0,1)})  $$

Some comments or further hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T(\overline{B(0,1))}=(T^{-1})^{-1}(\overline{B(0,1)})$. This  implies that $T(\overline{B(0,1))}$ is closed.

Since $B(0,1)\subset \overline{B(0,1)}$, we deduce that $T(B(0,1))\subset T(\overline{B(0,1)})$,
and $\overline{T(B(0,1))}\subset T(\overline{B(0,1)})$ since $T(\overline{B(0,1)})$ is closed.

$y\in T(\overline{B(0,1)})$ implies  there exists $x=lim_nx_n, x_n\in B(0,1)$ and $y=T(x)=T(lim_nx_n)=lim_nT(x_n)$ implies $y\in\overline{T(B(0,1))}$.

Comment: Helps a lot, thank you!

Comment: After thinking again about the last lines, why is it that $x_n \in B(0,1)$ and not $x_n \in X$? Thanks.

Comment: Because $y\in T(\overline{B(0,1)})$.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer already works. This answer is only for succinctness.

*Proof.*
By continuity of $T$, we have containment $T\left(\overline{B(0,1)}\right)\subset \overline{T\left(B(0,1)\right)}$ from $X$ to $Y$. Similarly, by the continuity of $T^{-1}$, we also have the reverse containment
$$T^{-1}\left(\overline{T\left(B(0,1)\right)}\right)\subset \overline{T^{-1}\left(T\left(B(0,1)\right)\right)}=\overline{B(0,1)} \Longleftrightarrow \overline{T\left(B(0,1)\right)}\subset T\left(\overline{B(0,1)}\right)$$
from $Y$ to $X$. Hence the two sets are equal. $\square$